# Finite Automata for regular expression

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

I am trying to construct finite automata for this regular expression:
Every block consisting of 5 characters need to contain at least two zeros. The regular expression would look sth like this:

(**00**(1|0)(1|0)(1|0)(1|0) + **0**(1|0)**0**(1|0)(1|0) + **0**(1|0)(1|0)**0**(1|0) + **0**(1|0)(1|0)(1|0)**0** + (1|0)**00**(1|0)(1|0) + (1|0)**0**(1|0)**0**(1|0) + (1|0)**0**(1|0)(1|0)**0** +
(1|0)(1|0)**00**(1|0) + (1|0)(1|0)**0**(1|0)**0** +
(1|0)(1|0)(1|0)**00** **)+**

The problem is this is a long regular expression and i am not sure if am doing it the correct way. I have no idea how we can make it shorter. I would be grateful for telling me the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. It is easier to first consider the complement of your language, which is the set of words containing at least one factor of length $5$ containing *at most* one $0$. Setting $A = \{0,1\}$ and $R = \{u \in \{0,1\}^5 \mid |u|_0 \leqslant 1\}$, the complement of your language is thus $A^*RA^*$ and thus your language is
$L = A^* - A^*RA^*$. You now have to find the minimal DFA of $L$ and then convert this DFA to a regular expression.

Note that the words of length $< 5$ are all in $L$ but do not match your regular expression.

Comment: but the length need to be at least 5

Comment: Why? It is not specified in your question.

Comment: as i understand the word need to be of size 5,10,15,20 and so on.

Comment: Then you should modify your question. And what about the word $0011111100$, which contains a block of 6 consecutive $1$'s? According to your definition, it should not be in the language...